# Where can I get list of mvc.action.command names in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to know where can I get list of mvc.action.command names in liferay 7. I want to override the class having `mvc.action.command=editArticle` as I need to make a custom `EditArticleAction`. This class is well defined in liferay 6.2 but I need its equivalent classs in liferay 7. So, please help. Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to achieve? Which application are you looking in?

Answer (score 0):

To create a action command you need to Implement the action by creating a class that implements the MVCActionCommand interface, your class must contain the '@Component' annotation. in your case your class should look like below code snippets.

    `@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
            "javax.portlet.name=your_portlet_name_YourPortlet",
            "mvc.command.name= editArticle"
        },
        service = MVCActionCommand.class
    )
    public class EditArticleMVCActionCommand extends BaseMVCActionCommand {
        // implement your action
    }`

for more detail you can go through this tutorial [DXP MVC Action](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/mvc-action-command).
hope this will help you, let me know if you have a further question in this.

Thanks,
Dipti

Comment: sorry i shared information on how to create a mvc action command, here is a tutorial to override the existing MVCActionCommand https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-mvc-commands

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure that out in my opinion is to use an index of whole Liferay code.

I've created [simple maven project](https://github.com/ktor/liferay-reference) that lists all Liferay packages as dependencies so you can import into your IDE. [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) provides excellent indexing/search features for maven projects.

Let's use the search for article update action as per your example. I have found with following regex query `mvc.command.name=/.*article` that action which updates article is implemented with `"mvc.command.name=/journal/update_article"` property in `UpdateArticleMVCActionCommand` class:

```java
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "javax.portlet.name=" + JournalPortletKeys.JOURNAL,
        "mvc.command.name=/journal/add_article",
        "mvc.command.name=/journal/update_article"
    },
    service = MVCActionCommand.class
)
public class UpdateArticleMVCActionCommand extends BaseMVCActionCommand {
```

Another benefit of the method is that you are given precise artifact coordinates once you find the code you need. In this case it's: `com.liferay:com.liferay.journal.web:3.0.41`.